# How to check if Firebase Facebook user exists - Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I want to check whether the user already exists in Firebase when they log in with Facebook or whether it's their first time. Firebase documentation just provides a function to login to facebook but doesn't mention if the user is new or not. A new user gets a new firebase user id, while an existing user just logs in.

By reading other similiar questions here- some people advised using AdditionalUserInfo.isNewUser for Javascript, but this function doesn't work for Unity code. Nothing about Unity here.

Basic code lines (after login to facebook)

```
Firebase.Auth.Credential credential =
Firebase.Auth.FacebookAuthProvider.GetCredential(accessToken);
auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
if (task.IsCanceled) {
Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync was canceled.");
return;
}
if (task.IsFaulted) {
Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " + 
task.Exception);
return;
}

Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
});
```

One solution that I was thinking about is to catch the exception - but couldn't find the exception code in their documentation - Firebase don't have a lot of info for Unity there

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief code that can help you.

```
public FirebaseAuth auth;

auth.FetchProvidersForEmailAsync(emailGotFromFacebook).ContinueWith((emailCheckingTask) =>
{
    List<string> allProviders = ((IEnumerable<string>)emailCheckingTask.Result).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < allProviders.Count; i++)
    {
        string provider = allProviders[i];
        Debug.Log(provider);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's interesting, the only thing that I'm worried about is that when a user signs in with facebook they get a message "app wants to use your email" and if they choose "not now"- they're logged in to facebook but I don't have their email address- also- if they change their email address on Facebook, I won't be able to identify them anymore based on the email key

Comment: Then you can save user's Facebook ID on your realtime database & check if that ID exists in your database or not. If it's there then user is not logging in first time. If it's not in your database then user is logging in first time with Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can check wheter it's the first login or if the user already exists using the following comparison: `newUser.Metadata.CreationTimestamp == newUser.Metadata.LastSignInTimestamp`

.. as shown below:

```
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
if (newUser.Metadata.CreationTimestamp == newUser.Metadata.LastSignInTimestamp) {
   Debug.Log("User signed for the first time");
}
else {
   Debug.Log("User already exists");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).