# Check if user is authenticated for the first time in Firebase Google Authentication in Unity(Android)

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine

How can I know if the user is signed in to the application for the first time or not?

There was a similar question.

[Check if user is authenticated for the first time in Firebase Google Authentication in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550149/check-if-user-is-authenticated-for-the-first-time-in-firebase-google-authenticat)

But I don't know how to do it when using Unity&c# as development tools.

Comment: How about this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70012470/10323242

Comment: Thx! It works well. But there's a small problem when I am testing. After I delete an account from Authentication section of the Firebase console,I can't create the account again. Overall, you solve my main problem~very appreciate.